# multiple form validation

Tags: jquery

If all asp.net controls are required to be within a form in order to be generated, how does one go about using the jquery validation plugin with multiple forms on the same page?

What I mean by that is, how can I have two forms both containing asp controls that can be validated independently with jquery validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate all of them:

```
$("form").validate();
```

...or only forms with a certain class:

```
$("form.validateMe").validate();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you want two forms in the first place.  ASP.NET, as far as I know, forces you to put all your controls in a single form.

So nevermind the validation at all.  The jQuery validation would be easy (See Craig's answer).  The two forms in ASP.NET is a different story.

You could probably hack it with iframes or something, but I'd advise against it.